# controller doesn't return any value using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I don't know whats wrong with my code, It doesn't return any data

Controller

```
function FundCluster(){
   $cluster=$this->input->post('funds');
   $this->load->model('Jev_model'); 
   $fund= $this->Jev_model->getFundCluster($cluster);
   $fundCluster= $fund['FundCluster'].$cluster;
   $this->insert_entry($fundCluster);

}
```

Model

```
function getFundCluster($cluster){
    $this->db->select('FundCluster');
    $this->db->from('fund');
    $this->db->where('id', $cluster); 
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result_array();

}
```

All i want is to get the value of this line

```
$fundCluster= $fund['FundCluster'].$cluster;
```

The purpose of this is to pass that variable to the other function

```
function insert_entry($fundcluster) {
$series=$fundcluster;
...
..
.
redirect('Jev/entryAccount/'.$series);
}
```

Comment: What data are you expecting? You don't seem to be outputting or returning anything.

Comment: You're still not outputting or returning anything, which was the main point.

Comment: How can i get the value of FundCluster? i dont know what's wrong with my query in the Model and i cant it in my controller.

Comment: I don't want to return it in the view. I will use it to another function for some purposes. But those codes doesn't return any value

Comment: are you sure you are getting values in $cluster and $fund  ?
 $cluster=$this->input->post('funds');
 $fund= $this->Jev_model->getFundCluster($cluster)

Comment: i would like to get the input data from my view so i used this line 
 $cluster=$this->input->post('funds');

and to pass that data to the vmodel
$fund= $this->Jev_model->getFundCluster($cluster);

Comment: try echoing out something in the controller and use `die()` to check that you are calling the controller correctly. Then check if you are getting any value in `$fundCluster` or `$fund`.

Comment: I tried passing dummy data in my FundCluster and pass it in the function insert_entry($fundcluster) but it did not return any data,, so i think the problem is i have a mistake in passing my variable from FundCluster to insert_entry

Answer (score 0):

You would probably have to use.

```
 $fund[0]['FundCluster']
```

Comment: Could you try to print the value of $query->result_array(); inside your model

Comment: like echo  $query->result_array();   ?

Comment: use print_r($query->result_array());

Comment: What do you mean by that? Does it return empty array?

Comment: It means, there's something wrong in your query. Try to print your query using $this->db->last_query() after you call your model function in controller and then run that query in your mysql client(phpmyadmin or whichever you use)

Comment: I tried passing dummy data in my FundCluster and pass it in the function insert_entry($fundcluster) but it did not return any data,, so i think the problem is i have a mistake in passing my variable from FundCluster to insert_entry

Comment: Not sure what it might be in this case, but check if there are any data type compatibilty issues

Comment: Thank you. i will check my codes if there are data type compatibility issues

Answer (score 0):

change this in model

```
return $query->result_array();
```

to

```
return $query->row();
```

in controller

```
$fundCluster= $fund['FundCluster'].$cluster;
```

to

```
$fundCluster= $fund->FundCluster;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
$query->row();
```

rather then

```
$query->result_array();
```

It will give you object and you can get value like

```
$fundCluster= $fund->FundCluster.$cluster;
```